# Airmon-ng start wlan0 - don't show up

Tags: aircrack-ng, airmon-ng

I'm doing [this tutorial](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/07/learn-to-hack-wifi-password-with-ubuntu.html).

When I'm typing:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

The only device that showed up is my network card.

If im typing:

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

it disconnects my network card.

[image]

Comment: The tutorial that you are trying to follow is obsolete. It was written 5 years ago. Find a more recent Kali Linux tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not answer to yourself, that is not the way how this website works, I am not very optimistc about the future of your topic... You should edit your first message to give more information if you have something to add. Saying so the answer is very simple: Your interface is not called `wlan0` but `wlx + mac of the device` (check your image, you have the name right under your eyes, i am not gonna write it down for you, it is long and your image isn't correctly inserted) due to the "smart and simple" (irony) systemd "new" naming policy.